# Fancybox2 unwanted fancybox-margin class added

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've a loader overlay showing when I click on an ajax fancybox.
But there is always a fancybox class added to it.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewsney5o/).

```
<div class="loading hide">Loading&#8230;</div>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
    click me
</a>

$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function () {
        $('.loading').removeClass('hide');
    },
    beforeShow: function () {
        $('.loading').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

When you click on the link, show source on the result, there is a `fancybox-margin` added.

This class is only added when the `.loading` element has the  `position:fixed`

Is there a way I can tell fancybox to not add this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to hack the original fancybox js file. If you do so, you will have to do it again the day you update a new version.

Just add to you custom fancybox initialization script the option

```
helpers: {
    overlay: {
        locked: false
    }
}
```

and the *class* `fancybox-margin` won't be added

Answer (score 1):

Only by modifying source. Remove these lines (1833-1835):

```
                $('*').filter(function(){
                    return ($(this).css('position') === 'fixed' && !$(this).hasClass("fancybox-overlay") && !$(this).hasClass("fancybox-wrap") );
                }).addClass('fancybox-margin');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the Fancybox code and comment out the following:

```
if (this.margin !== false) {
  $('*').filter(function(){
    return ($(this).css('position') === 'fixed' && !$(this).hasClass("fancybox-overlay") && !$(this).hasClass("fancybox-wrap") );
  }).addClass('fancybox-margin');

  this.el.addClass('fancybox-margin');
}
```

But beware dragons - I have no idea what effect this will have on the placement of the popup.

You'd probably be better having a look at the css file and playing with inspector to see what this does though first.